# View plain text files with different background colors in Mac OSX, for different programming languages

Tags: macos, applescript

I work with Mac OS X Leopard. I usually have 5 or 10 text files opened at the same time with different programming languages; one for a bash script, another for a python one, etc. When I use exposé all of them look the same, so it is difficult to select them.

I wonder how could I work with just plain text files in OSX, so when they are opened in an editor the background color changes or some other thign, so when using exposé it is clear to me which window belongs to what language.

I thought about inserting some kind of info to the last line of each document, and then creat some applescript that converts it to RTF or someother text document which includes color in bacjground, so then it is opened with textmate or someother app.

Do you know a better approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try smultron... it's free and I think it does what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Some editors allows different settings for different programming languages. Try TextMate or BBEdit, for example...